# MVCContrib RowAttributes overrides Attributes grid, how to have both?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I have a grid that works perfectly with

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults).Columns(column =>
{
//grid code here
}).Attributes(@class => "grid", width => "100%")
```

This is tagged to the css of:

```
.gridrow
{
 border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.gridrow_alternate
{
 background-color: #F2F2EA;
 border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

Which is all fine and places the alternative colours on the grid.

However I want to override certain grid rows with a greyed out row if the data brough back is invalid.

So I tried .RowAttributes

```
.RowAttributes(data => new Hash(@class => data.Item.Inactive ? "inactive" : ""))
```

with the css addition of:

```
.inactive 
{ 
border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

However this will override all the grid rows to now be "" or "inactive" as it needs to have the expression in for if else (or is there another way to write it) so it just has the if part of the statement? I have tried to put just the if statement in there but it complains I am missing a return statement so can not do it.

I want to keep gridrow and gridrow_Alternative as it is and simply override one of those dynamically...

So it would changed from

gridrow 
gridrow_Alternative
gridrow
gridrow_Alternative
gridrow

to be:

gridrow 
gridrow_Alternative
inactive
gridrow_Alternative
gridrow

So it keeps the alternating color bands and then if one is inactive it changes that one singularly to inactive in the TR like so:

```
<tr class="gridrow">
<tr class="gridrow_Alternative">
<tr class="inactive">
<tr class="gridrow_Alternative">
<tr class="gridrow">
```

Has anyone done this or can they assist as I cant find anything like this on the net, which I thought was strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the SQL Query - you could add a Row number to the data (for MSSQL see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)

Then check for the mod of the row number/2 - if 0 then class = "gridrow" - if not, class = "gridrow_alternate"
e.g:

```
    .RowAttributes(data => new Hash(@class => data.Item.Inactive ? "inactive" : : ((data.Item.Row % 2) == 0 ? "gridrow" : "gridrow_alternate"))))
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I came across this as I was looking for a similar solution. The answer from mon12345 seem a bit complex. There is an cleaner way to get the desired result if you use the **data.IsAlternate** property

```
.RowAttributes(
    data => new Hash(@class => data.Item.Inactive ? "inactive" : 
           ((data.IsAlternate ? "gridrow" : "gridrow_alternate")))
)
```